# Predict with biglm factors

Tags: r, bigdata, prediction

Why does predict with biglm differ from predict with lm?

Here is my code to generate data: (admittedly sloppy)

```
require(data.table)
require(biganalytics)

#create a data set with factor variables and one continuous numerical variable 
LETTERS702 <- c(LETTERS, sapply(LETTERS, function(x) paste0(x, LETTERS)))
data = data.table(ded = runif(100), cont = runif(100), fac1 = as.factor(LETTERS702[1:10]))
data[, cont := as.factor(ifelse(cont < .25, 100, 
                  ifelse(cont < .5, 200, 
                         ifelse( cont < .75, 300,
                                 cont))))]
newdata = data.table(ded = runif(50), cont = runif(50), fac1 = as.factor(LETTERS702[7:12]))
newdata[, cont := as.factor(ifelse(cont < .25, 100, 
                     ifelse(cont < .5, 200, 
                            ifelse( cont < .75, 300,
                                    cont))))]

#add the levels from the old data to the new data
levels(newdata$fac1) = c(levels(newdata$fac1),levels(data$fac1))
levels(newdata$cont) = c(levels(newdata$cont),levels(data$cont))

levels(data$fac1) = c(levels(data$fac1),levels(newdata$fac1))
levels(data$cont) = c(levels(data$cont),levels(newdata$cont))
```

Now when I run an lm regression and try to create predicted values in the new data table, it works as expected:

```
reg =lm(ded ~ fac1 + cont, data = data)
summary(reg)

newdata[fac1 %in% data$fac1 & cont %in% data$cont, ded_hat := predict(reg, newdata[fac1 %in% data$fac1 & cont %in% data$cont, ])]

head(newdata)
         ded cont fac1   ded_hat
1: 0.1820960  200    G 0.4636306
2: 0.2561465  300    H 0.5412485
3: 0.8711127  300    I 0.5351451
4: 0.9839877  200    J 0.5737994
5: 0.8802973  200    K        NA
6: 0.1385486  200    L        NA
```

But when I try to use `biglm`, All of the new predicted values are NA:

```
reg = biglm(ded ~ fac1 + cont, data = data)
summary(reg)

newdata[fac1 %in% data$fac1 & cont %in% data$cont, ded_hat := predict(reg, newdata[fac1 %in% data$fac1 & cont %in% data$cont, ])]

head(newdata)
         ded cont fac1 ded_hat
1: 0.1820960  200    G      NA
2: 0.2561465  300    H      NA
3: 0.8711127  300    I      NA
4: 0.9839877  200    J      NA
5: 0.8802973  200    K      NA
6: 0.1385486  200    L      NA
```

What is going on here? What do I need to change to get predict to work for biglm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the work around I ended up using:

1. Be sure the new data has the all the levels of the old data
2. Use the dummies package to expand into dummies for each level manually
3. Run the regression and make the prediction

   ```
   require(data.table)
   require(dummies)

   #create a data set with factor variables and one continuous numerical variable 
   LETTERS702 <- c(LETTERS, sapply(LETTERS, function(x) paste0(x, LETTERS)))
   data = data.table(ded = runif(100), cont = runif(100), fac1 = as.factor(LETTERS702[1:10]))
   data[, cont := as.factor(ifelse(cont < .25, 100, 
                 ifelse(cont < .5, 200, 
                        ifelse( cont < .75, 300,
                                cont))))]

   newdata = data.table(ded = runif(50), cont = runif(50), fac1 = as.factor(LETTERS702[7:12]))
   newdata[, cont := as.factor(ifelse(cont < .25, 100, 
                    ifelse(cont < .5, 200, 
                           ifelse( cont < .75, 300,
                                   cont))))]

   #add the levels from the old data to the new data
   levels(newdata$fac1) = c(levels(newdata$fac1),levels(data$fac1))
   levels(newdata$cont) = c(levels(newdata$cont),levels(data$cont))

   #generate a dummy for each fac1
   data = as.data.table(dummy.data.frame(data, names = c("fac1","cont")))
   newdata = as.data.table(dummy.data.frame(newdata, names = c("fac1","cont"), drop = F))

   #a list of variable names in both data sets
   datanames = (names(data))
   newdatanames = (names(newdata))
   varnames = subset(newdatanames, newdatanames %in% datanames)

   #regression
   reg = lm(ded ~ ., data = data)

   #prediction
   newdata[, ded_hat := predict(reg, newdata)]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `biglm` doesn't automatically drop unused levels, or adjust for different sets of factor levels in a sophisticated way.

If you do

```
reg1 = lm(ded ~ fac1 + cont, data = data)
reg2 = biglm(ded ~ fac1 + cont, data = data)
```

and compare the coefficients, you'll see that the non-`NA` values match but there are 14 extra `NA` values ... which are presumably propagating through the prediction computation.

```
length(coef(reg1))
## [1] 36
length(coef(reg2))
## [1] 50
## unname()  and c() remove extraneous attributes 
all.equal(unname(coef(reg1)),unname(c(na.omit(coef(reg2))))) ## TRUE
```

If you use `droplevels`

```
reg3 = biglm(ded ~ fac1 + cont, data = droplevels(data))
```

then the coefficients match, but the prediction fails differently (`Error in x %*% coef(object) : non-conformable arguments`), presumably because there is a different set of levels in the new data - you'll have to work a little harder to set the factor levels so they match ...